# `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` returns `null`

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

The first cell of my `DataGridView` is `ComboBox`. I am adding members in this column like below...

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string qry = "SELECT [NAME] FROM [PERSONS]";

// running ExcecuteNonQuery() function in globalData.cs file
dt = globalData.q.select(qry, globalData.connectionstring);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    (this.dataGrid.Columns["Name"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).Items.Add(row[0].ToString());
}
```

and checking on `Cell_Leave` event

```
if ((this.dataGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You must select one option.");
}
```

But the value returns `null` every time even though the value is selected from the `ComboBoxCell`. Here `Cell` is not `null` but the value of the cell is null.

What's wrong with this?

Comment: datagridviewcomboboxcolumn add in runtime or already added in datagridview

Comment: already added in `DataGridView`.

Comment: bind your datagridviewcombobox in form load event ex: Name .Datasource ="yoursource"; Name.DisplayMember="Dispmem"; Name.ValueMember="Valuemem";

Comment: `(this.dataGrid.Columns["Name"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource = dt;
                (this.dataGrid.Columns["Name"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).ValueMember = "NAME";
                (this.dataGrid.Columns["Name"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DisplayMember = (this.dataGrid.Columns["Name"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).ValueMember;`    I did it but still null value is returned on `Cell_Leave` event.

Comment: fill DisplayMember field and did you check Cell_endedit event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this like below....

```
    private void DataGrid_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.dataGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.Control is ComboBox)
        {
            ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
            comboBox.KeyDown += this.DataGridComboBox_KeyDown;
        }
    }

    private void DataGridComboBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S) && !(e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C))
        {
            try
            {
                var currentcell = this.dataGrid.CurrentCellAddress;
                var sendingCB = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
                DataGridViewComboBoxCell cel = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)this.dataGrid.Rows[currentcell.Y].Cells[0];
                cel.Value = sendingCB.EditingControlFormattedValue.ToString();
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```